# Trying to save a JSON to file but getting an AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dumps'

Tags: python, json

My first program is to play a game and keep a high score of the win in a file. I want to use JSON and I am able to create a file if it does not already exist, but not able to add to it (and the gaming session is still the same one).

I get the error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dumps'`.

Code is:

```
score = {
    "score" : round_counter,
    "name" : player["name"],
    "hp left" : player["hitpoints"]
}

if os.path.isfile('score.json'):

    print("your score has been added")
    json = json.dumps(score)
    f = open("score.json","a")
    f.write(json)
    f.close()

else :
    print ("database doesn't exist so it was created!")
    json = json.dumps(score)
    f = open("score.json","x")
    f.write(json)
    f.close()
```

It seems like the problem only is when the terminal is in its current session that it gives this error, meaning that if I close the terminal and run a new game it will behave as expected for the first time, then `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dumps'` appears on second score saving.

Comment: I tried the code and it works fine, if you are doing it in terminal make sure to not use `json.dumps(score)` twice

Comment: rename `json = json.dumps(score)` to something else `string = json.dumps(score)`. It might fix the problem, cant say more without seeing more of the code.

Comment: @wishmaster: The code does not "works fine".

Comment: @martineau I ran the code 4 times (with my own dict),no error.Anyway the question has been edited many times now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your error :

```py
json = json.dumps(score)
```

You overwrite the json package in the namespace.
After that line, json is not a package anyomre, it is a simple string.

You can easily fix it by giving another name to your json variable, `json_dump` should be fine.

---

```py
score = {
        "score" : round_counter,
        "name" : player["name"],
        "hp left" : player["hitpoints"]
    }

if os.path.isfile('score.json'):

    print("your score has been added")
    json_dump = json.dumps(score)
    f = open("score.json","a")
    f.write(json_dump)
    f.close()  

else :
    print ("database doesn't exist so it was created!")
    json_dump = json.dumps(score)
    f = open("score.json","x")
    f.write(json_dump)
    f.close()
```

Comment: @wishmaster OP says it works only the first time, so it might be the problem Valentin M said.

Comment: @wishmaster I assume this code sample is in a function or in a `while` loop. If it is not the issue, more code will be required to solve this issue.

Comment: "You overwrite the json package in the namespace. After that line, json is not a package anyomre, it is a simple string." This was exactly what my problem was. Now I undrestand. Thanks.